# One line block and if condition

Tags: ruby

I have:

```
foos.each do |foo|
  unless foo
    puts "Foo is missing"
    next
  end
  # rest of business logic goes here
end
```

I would like to write the last part of it better, something like

```
{ puts "Foo is missing"; next } unless foo
```

Unfortunately, this does not work. Does anybody know a way to write two (blocks of) commands inline with `if` condition?

Comment: Wow such good answers so quickly

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just use parentheses:

```
(puts 'a'; puts 'b') if true
#=> a
#=> b
```

Comment: Those are not brackets.

Comment: In my language they are called _parentesi_, Wikipedia says [they are also called _round brackets_](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bracket#Parentheses_.28_.29), but I don't really know which is the correct way to call them; fell free to edit the answer if you feel confident

Comment: What you say about Italian carries over to English. In the most standard English dialect, educated people will call it parenthesis.

Comment: Ok, I trust you :) fixed. In Italian there isn't the _parenteheses/brackets_ distinction, _parentheses_ are called _parentesi tonde_ (or just _parentesi_), _square brackets_ are called _parentesi quadre_, and so on, so I mix up

Answer (score 3):

What you are looking for can be done with parentheses:

```
(puts "Foo is missing"; next) unless foo
```

But in this particular case, it is better to write:

```
next puts "Foo is missing" unless foo
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `begin..end` block:

```
begin puts "Foo is missing"; next end unless foo
```

Answer (score 1):

```
foos.each { |foo| foo or ( puts "Foo is missing"; next )
  # the rest of the business logic goes here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `or` syntax

```
[1,2,3].each do |x|
  puts 'two' or next if x == 2
  puts x
end

#=> 1
#=> "two"
#=> 3
```